# Crop Image With Desire Rect

Tags: ios, ios-camera

Many questions are available on SO, but unfortunately I couldn't solve my problem using them.
I've added a overlay view on my camera, and now want to get image within the blue border (only water bottle).

I tried code chunks like following

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);

[UIImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; 

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

but having two issues

1. Either cropped image is getting too big
2. The orientation changes to -90.

for point 1, I think I'm providing `cropRect` too small thats why it showing very small part of image with too zoomed view. on my other `viewController` I have `UIImageView` (where cropped image need to display) of same size as camera rect within blue border. 
So question is how to crop the image and what values should I provide for `cropRect`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the image size 1280* 1080 and your crop view size 320*480 You need to do the following

1. Convert your crop view's frame to Image size rect (0, 0,  1280, 1080) by find the scale factor

   ```
   float xScale = 1280 / 320;
   float yScale = 1080 / 480;

   float scaleFactor = (xScale < yScale) ? xScale : yScale;
   ```
2. Multiply cropView frame by scale factor. This will map the screen coordinates to image size coordinates. Then use the new cropRect with the

   ```
   CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);
   ```

The problem with different orientation is that CoreGraphics uses a different coordinate system as compare to view's coordinate system. [Quartz 2D Coordinate Systems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC) so try setting

```
   [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef].imageOrientation = largeImage.imageOrientation
```

Comment: what values I need to provide in `cropRect` ?

Comment: Assuming image size as 1280* 1080 and crop rect as {40, 50,  320, 480}. Convert croprect by {40* scaleFactor, 50* scaleFactor,  320* scaleFactor, 480* scaleFactor} and use this new rect for croping

Comment: for `imageOrientation` it says `assignment to read only property.`

Comment: I tried following code for orientation
`UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef
                        scale:1.0
                  orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation];`
but now image is showing like this
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37107813/image-orientation.png